# Suppose the function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at any $c>0$. Show that this function is differentiable at any $c>0$ and find $f'(c)$.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose the function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at any $c>0$. Show that this function is differentiable at any $c>0$ and find $f'(c)$.

I know that if a function is continuous any any $c>0$ then for any sequence $x_n \rightarrow c$ we have that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$

Now I want to show that $\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c} \rightarrow f'(c)$

So suppose that the function is continuous then let $x_n \rightarrow c$ then we know that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$ now I can't see how to connect this to what I want to show.

Can I go with trying to evaluate what the limit will be? such as $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{\sqrt(x_n)-\sqrt(c)}{x_n-c}$ then multiplying by the conjugate $\sqrt(x_n) + \sqrt(c)$ I end up with $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt(c)}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt(c)}$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I don't know how far you have gone in Calculus but you will probably soon learn the general formula for derivatives of powers of x: $(x^n)'= nx^{n- 1}$.  Here, $\sqrt{x}= x^{1/2}$ so its derivative is $(1/2)x^{1/2- 1}= (1/2)x^{-1/2}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous for every $x>0$. Let $c>0$ then 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{c+h}-\sqrt{c}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{c+h-c}{h(\sqrt{c+h}+\sqrt{c})}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+h}+\sqrt{c}}$$
Since $f$ is continuous then we can pass the limit inside the square root.
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+h}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt{c+h}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lim_{h\to 0}(c+h)}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$$
Exactly similar calculations you can show that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c)-f(c-h)}{h}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$$
By definition of the derivative at $c$ we have
$$f'(c):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c)-f(c-h)}{h}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$$